# How parse XML with metadata in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a problem with parsing above XML code. It doesn't look like normal XML structure - in the top of document is schema, which describe fields. Is there any simple method for parsing it?

```
<metadata>
      <item name="number" type="xs:string" length="42"/>
      <item name="artist" type="xs:string" length="62"/>
      <item name="title" type="xs:string" length="502"/>
      <item name="title supplement" type="xs:string" length="502"/>
      <item name="price" type="xs:decimal" scale="2" precision="12"/>
</metadata>
<data>
    <row>
        <value>88697562032</value>
        <value>1979 Revival Cast Recording</value>
        <value>Oklahoma!</value>
        <value>Softpack</value>
        <value>25</value>
    </row>
    (...)
    <row>
        <value>88697919802</value>
        <value>2CELLOS (Sulic &amp; Hauser)</value>
        <value>2CELLOS</value>
        <value>Three Language Booklet Version</value>
        <value>39.6</value>
    </row>
</data>
```

Comment: Basically that's not an XML document. It would be if it were wrapped in a root element, but as it is, you're going to have a hard time parsing it.

Comment: When you say 'parse' what is it you want to do with the xml?  It would be simple to process each <row/> as you know, by field order, what each value represents.